# Use loop to skip an item of a list in a StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, for-loop

I am retrieving a list of users with a Stream and I need to ignore the current user. I did this once with a Future List, but with StreamBuilder an error appears when defining the list of documents.

**So here's what's working (Future):**

```
Future<List<Users>> _getUsers() async {
    Firestore db = Firestore.instance;

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await db
        .collection('users')
        .getDocuments();

    List<Users> usersList = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot item in querySnapshot.documents) {
      var data = item.data;
      if (data["id"] == _userId) continue;

      Users user = Users();
      user.name = data["name"];
      user.username = data["username"];
      user.id = data["id"];

      usersList.add(user);
    }

    return usersList;
  }
```

**And this is not working (Stream):**

```
startConnecting() {
    return Expanded(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream:Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                "Nothing."
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                _buildListUsers(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _buildListUsers(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    List<Users> usersList = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot item in document) {
```

> In that last 'document' an error message appears: "The type 'DocumentSnapshot' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable."

```
      var data = item.data;
      if (data["id"] == _userId) continue;

      Users user = Users();
      user.name = document["name"];
      user.username = document["username"];
      user.id = document["id"];

      usersList.add(user);

      return ListTile(
        ...
      );
    }
  }
```

I looked for this error but did not find anything like it. It must be something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Don't do this: `stream:Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots()`.  Read the second and third paragraphs of the docs about StreamBuilder very carefully.  They explain why what you are doing is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop through a DocumentSnapshot, because as stated, it's not an iterable object, it's a single document. So change this:

```
Widget _buildListUsers(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    List<Users> usersList = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot item in document) {
```

To this:

```
Widget _buildListUsers(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    List<Users> usersList = [];
    //for (DocumentSnapshot item in document) { ==> comment out this for loop
  var data = document.data;
    //keep your logic here as it

    //remove the closing curly brace at the end, because there is no more for loop.
```

To answer your second question in the comment, do this:

```
if (data["id"] != _userId) {

      Users user = Users();
      user.name = data["name"];
      user.username = data["username"];
      user.id = data["id"];

      usersList.add(user);
    }
```

Comment: I did this but the 'item' becomes undefined and it is not possible to use continue statement outside a loop or switch

Comment: Also change it to this: `var data = document.data;`. You don't need item anymore, because there is no for loop.

Comment: Got it. Is there some alternative for the continue statement?

Comment: Is the problem resolved? I also can't see the continue in your stream builder. You can always use a `return` to stop the proccess, instead of using `uid ==uid continue` => `uid!=uid return`.

Comment: No. I mean this part `if (data["id"] == _userId) continue;`. I want the current user to be skipped while building the list and not stop the process. Is there a way to do that without using continue?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer and added the method, check it out and consider marking this as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the list in StreamBuilder, use ListView.builder to build the UI. Inside the listview.builder's build method, check if (list[index].uid==currentUserUid).
If yes, return invisible widget.

example code:

```
List<User> list;
return ListView.builder(
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     if(list[index].uid == currentUserUid)
       return Visibility(visible:false, child: Text(''));
     else
        return something;
   }
);
```